# Curvature decay of Ricci expanders

Tags: parabolic-pde, ricci-flow

Let $M$ be a gradient Ricci expander with nonnegative curvature operator. Assume $\Sigma$ is its space of directions at infinity (so $M$ looks like a cone over $\Sigma$).

> What is the curvature decay of $M$ in the *radial* directions?

The word *radial* is important --- if $\Sigma$ has curvature $>1$ at some point, then the decay of curvature in the normal-to-radial directions is quadratic or worse (in the product $\mathbb{R}\times M$ it does not go to zero).

**Comments.**

- The first formula on page 167 of "Hamilton's Ricci flow" by Chow, Lu and Ni implies that the curvature decay is exponential in 2-dimensional case. (Thanks to the comment of Hee Kwon Lee.)
- In principle I need an estimate that works for general expander (so far I hope that it is exponential).
- Formally, the question can be formulated the following way: *what is the rate of decay of the lowest eigenvalue of Ricci tensor?*
- An other way to formalize the question is to find the decay of $\langle\mathrm{Ricc}\,u,u\rangle$ where $u$ is the direction to a fixed point. In this setting the decay is at least quadratic for $\mathbb{R}\times M$, I expect that it has to be quadratic, but have no idea how to prove it.
- Yet an other way to formalize the problem is to estimate the decay of $\langle \mathrm{Ricc}\,\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle$, where $f$ is the potential of the expander. The potential $f$ is convex and almost proportional to $\mathrm{dist}_o^2$ so we can think that its gradient points in the *radial* direction. We have the following identity (9.66 and 9.67 in "Hamilton's Ricci flow" by Chow, Lu and Ni)
  $$2\cdot\mathrm{Ricc}\,\nabla f=\nabla \mathrm{R};$$
  in particular,
  $$2\cdot\langle \mathrm{Ricc}\,\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle=\langle\nabla \mathrm{R},\nabla f\rangle.$$
  Since $\langle \mathrm{Ricc}\,\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle\ge 0$, it implies that scalar curvature is monotonic along the $f$-gradient curve; it also gives an integral estimate for $\langle \mathrm{Ricc}\,\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle$ in terms of change of scalar curvature along the curve. All this seems to be very close to what I need. (Thanks to Alix Deruelle for this observation.)

Comment: For the first question in comment, reference is 164p. in Hamilton's Ricci flow - Chow, Lu and Li.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee thank you, so it is exponential (I mean, did I understand correctly the first formula on page 167?)

Comment: Yes. And for the remaining, (11) problem in 390p. and "On the asymptotic behavior of expanding gradient Ricci solitons - Chen" may be helpful.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee, It seems that (10) is false --- expanders that start from a polyhedral  cone have strictly positive curvature operator, but the scalar curvature does not converge to 0.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee I am quite sure that (11) also fails expanders starting from  a polyhedral cone.